# Receiving 400's from the Data Extract SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, data-export

I'm receiving 400's when trying to set up a Data Extract Activity.

Request:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "SOAPAction: Create" -d "$(cat dataextract.txt)" "https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx"
```

The contents of dataextract.txt are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <header>
      <security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <usernametoken>
            <username>jared@lytics.io</username>
            <password>#OUR_VALID_PASSWORD#</password>
         </usernametoken>
      </security>
   </header>
   <body>
      <extractrequestmsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <requests>
            <id>c7219016-a7f0-4c72-8657-1ec12c28a0db</id>
            <parameters>
               <parameter>
                  <name>StartDate</name>
                  <value>01/22/2015 12:00:00 AM</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>EndDate</name>
                  <value>01/23/2015 12:00:00 AM</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>OutputFileName</name>
                  <value>Example.zip</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>AccountIDs</name>
                  <value />
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>Attributes</name>
                  <value />
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>CharacterEncoding</name>
                  <value>Default</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ColumnDelimiter</name>
                  <value>Default</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>EmailSendDefinitionExternalKey</name>
                  <value />
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractAttributes</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractBounces</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractClickImpressions</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractClicks</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractConversions</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>extractListMembershipChanges</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>extractLists</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractNotSent</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractOpens</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractSendImpressions</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractSendJobImpressions</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractSendJobs</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractSent</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>extractStatusChanges</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractSubscribers</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractSurveyResponses</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>ExtractUnsubs</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>Format</name>
                  <value>csv</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>IncludeAllListMembers</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>IncludeAllSubscribers</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>IncludeInferredOpens</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>IncludeMilliseconds</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>IncludeTestSends</name>
                  <value>true</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>IncludeUnsubReason</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>IncludeUserAgentInformation</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>QuoteText</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>SendIDs</name>
                  <value />
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>TextQualifier</name>
                  <value />
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>Timezone</name>
                  <value>1</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>UnicodeOutput</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>UseIDs</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>
                  <name>UseLocalTZinQuery</name>
                  <value>false</value>
               </parameter>
            </parameters>
         </requests>
      </extractrequestmsg>
   </body>
</envelope>
```

I have three questions about this...

- How can I correct my API call?
- Does creating a Data Extract also start it? (In the UI it's a separate step.)
- How do I select which FTP site I'd like to send the file to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `400` because of the `SOAPAction`.  You should be able to use `SOAPAction: Extract` -

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "SOAPAction: Extract" -d "$(cat dataextract.txt)" "https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx"
```

This will perform the data extract, and create a file on the EFTP server.  If you need to transfer the file, you follow this call with a `FileTransferActivity` to move from one location to another, and specify the location there.